# JavaScript Autoloader: How To Recover From Errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, amd, autoload

I have a proof-of-concept working for a JavaScript autoloader, but it currently suffers from a major flaw: it requires the code to be re-executed in its entirety rather than simply trying again from the line that failed.

Here is the prototype:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = function(){
    console.log('Initialize App');
    var test = new Test();
    var foo = new Foo();
    var bar = new Bar();
};

var autoload = function(app){

    var recover = function(error){
        var name = error.message.split(' ')[0];
        console.log('Loading '+name);
        //A file could be synchronously loaded here instead
        this[name] = function(){
            console.log(name+' has been dynamically created');
        };
        load(app);
    };

    var load = function(app){
        try {
            app();
        } catch (error){
            if (error.name == "ReferenceError"){
                console.log(error.message);
                recover(error, app);
            }
        }
    };

    load(app);

};

autoload(app);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**How It's Supposed To Work**

The idea is that all of your application code would get executed within the `app` function. Eventually, if I can get it working properly, you could also pass in a dependency map to autoloader with the app function to synchronously load dependencies when a function is not defined. The dependency map would simply be an object mapping function names to file names.

**How It Currently Works**

If you don't feel like trying it out, the above code outputs the following to the console:

```
Initialize App 
Test is not defined 
Loading Test 
Initialize App 
Test has been dynamically created
Foo is not defined 
Loading Foo 
Initialize App 
Test has been dynamically created
Foo has been dynamically created
Bar is not defined 
Loading Bar 
Initialize App 
Test has been dynamically created
Foo has been dynamically created
Bar has been dynamically created
```

The complete `app` function is re-executed each time the autoloader catches an error. Obviously, this is less than ideal for a number of reasons.

**Recovering From The Error**

To move to the next step for making this work, I need to find a way to recover from the error without re-executing the entire `app` function. The `error` object from the `catch` block does provide both the line number and file name where the error occurred, but so far, I haven't been able to find a way to take advantage of that information. There are three general approaches that I can think of:

1. Restart script execution at the given line
2. Restart script execution at the beginning, but skip all lines until the given line
3. Grab the file as a string, split it into an array by line number, and `eval` the remaining lines.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find information on either of the first two approaches. Of the three, #1 seems like it would be more ideal, but I would certainly be open to other creative suggestions as well. As far as I can tell, JavaScript doesn't provide a way to start script execution at an arbitrary line number. #3 *might* work, but I'm not sure it would be very performant. The only way I can think of doing it would be to require an extra request each time to load the file text into a string.

**The Questions**

This is admittedly pushing the boundaries of how dependencies could be loaded in JavaScript. I'm not even sure if it is possible because I don't know if JavaScript allows for this type of error recovery. That said, I'm interested in exploring it further until I find out it's absolutely impossible.

In the interests of getting this working:

1. Is there a way to start script execution at an arbitrary line of JavaScript?
2. Are there other approaches to this that might be more fruitful? Feel free to be creative!

Taking a step back to look at the bigger picture (assuming I can get this to work):

1. Is a JavaScript autoloader something that people would even want?
2. What are the advantages/disadvantages to an autoloader like this vs. an approach like AMD?
3. What kind of performance issues would be encountered with this approach? Would the performance hit be too much to make it worth it?

Comment: Auto-loading things like that seems a bit too ‘magic’ to me. Besides that, I do think you'll have quite a bit of trouble making it work at all. I don't know of any way you can recover from an error and keep running from that point, and while you have provided some options you've thought of, I don't think they would be able to interact decently with scoping and closed-over variables. If you want this sort of magic approach, I think you'd have much more success using a preprocessor with static analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @icktoofay. I agree, it is somewhat "magical".  Good point on the scoping, etc. Of course, if there is no great way to recover from the errors, none of that will even matter. At this point, I'm just exploring. It's entirely possible that it just can't be done with JavaScript.

Comment: @icktoofay `recover from an error and keep running from that point` stacking up promises would work for asynch tasks. Have a function that loops through an array of objects with functions that return a promise and stack them. When fail then call a recover (if there) and call itself recursively using the index where it failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of complicated to make, throwing and catching is kind of expensive as well. You could use `typeof window["Test"]!=="function"` and then create it instead of using the try catch like this.

But for a general recover and continue approach the following code would do the trick.

```
var app = (function(i){
  var objects=new Array(3),
  fnNames=["Test","Foo","Bar"];
  return function(){
    var len=fnNames.length
     ,test,foo,bar;
    //check if closure vars have been reset, if so
    // this has ran successfully once so don't do anything?
    if(objects===false){
      console.log("nothing to do, initialized already");
      return;
    }
    while(i<len){
      try{
        objects[i] = new window[fnNames[i]]();
        i++;
      }catch(e){
        if (e.name == "TypeError"){//different syntax different error
          throw {"fnName":fnNames[i]};
        }
      }
    }
    //store instances in the variables
    test = objects[0];
    foo = objects[1];
    bar = objects[2];
    //reset closure vars assuming you only call app once
    //  when it's successful
    i=null;objects=false;
    console.log("Got all the instances",test,foo,bar);
  };
}(0));

var autoload = function(app){
  var recover = function(name){
    console.log('Loading '+name);
    //A file could be synchronously loaded here instead
    this[name] = function(){
      this.name=name;
      console.log(this.name+' has been dynamically created');
    };
    load(app);
  };

  var load = function(app){
    try {
      app();
    } catch (error){
      //if statement here no longer needed
      // object thrown has fnName (function name)
      recover(error.fnName, app);
    }
  };
  load(app);
};

autoload(app);
autoload(app);
```